# What are the use cases for anonymous SSL cipher suites?

Tags: tls, cipher-selection

SSL supports several anonymous cipher suites such as TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. When these are used, no authentication is performed and no certificates are exchanged. This means that if they are used, you are at risk of MitM attacks.

Previously, I have only seen these enabled when someone has enabled every single cipher suite by mistake. Today, I noticed that Nationwide online banking has a [single anonymous cipher suite enabled](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=onlinebanking.nationwide.co.uk).

This leads me to believe it was added deliberately, rather than accidentally.

What are the use cases for anonymous cipher suites on a website?

Comment: Upvoted for bringing the Nationwide master... minds to light.

Comment: Contact Nationwise tech support, or their abuse contact, with a link to the [ssllabs](https://ssllabs.com) test results for their site.  They need to fix this immediately, and find out who added that cipher suite.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What are the use cases for anonymous cipher suites on a website?

None. This is just a severe mistake and therefore the grade is capped to F.
None of the browsers offers anonymous cipher suites (at least by default) so no connection with a browser will be established this way. But it might well be that some mobile banking apps make the same mistake.

Answer (score 12):

That TLS includes such capability is not without good reason.

It provides for confidentiality without the need for a certificate authority - an endpoint must be configured to remember what certificates it will accept, instead of which certificate authorities it will accept. This is a completely different trust model from that generally used on the internet, and should not be used on a public website.

I would not expect this cipher to be available in any browser.

Comment: +1 for the nice explanation of an alternative use case where anon suites could somewhat make sense, given that TLS is widely deployed and not only used for web services.

Comment: "an endpoint must be configured to remember what certificates it will accept, instead of which certificate authorities it will accept" - This does not actually work with anon suites. There is no certificate exchange when using anon suites so you will not be able to accept or reject any certificates.