# Secure communication between peers with ANON ciphers and password authentication

Tags: ciphers

Using ANON ciphers (No certificates required/used) while establishing connection and later using the username/password for authentication considered secure communication?

Are there any flaws in it, like 'Man In The Middle' (MITM) attacks possible?

Comment: How do you perform key exchange between client/server with this protocol?

Comment: @user52472 I don't perform any key exchange.

Comment: How do the client/server get the keys to encrypt/decrypt data?

Comment: @user52472 Is it mandatory to provide keys while using ANON ciphers?

Comment: Ok, nevermind.  I misunderstood your original question.  I will add my answer below.  Why are you considering anonymous ciphers instead of standard SSL?

Answer (score 1):

A large portion of the value of SSL/TLS is the validation of the authenticity of the application you are communicating with.  Yes, a MITM attack is possible in the scenario you describe.  See this other [SE answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/113535/what-are-the-use-cases-for-anonymous-ssl-cipher-suites) for more information.