# How can a Trusted Platform Module "enhance network security"?

Tags: tpm

I've recently bought a motherboard, which has support for a Trusted Platform Module. On the topic, the manual states the following:

> This connector supports Trusted Platform Module (TPM) system, which can securely store keys, digital certificates, passwords and data. A TMP system also helps enhance network security, protects digital identities and ensures platform integrity.

A copy of the manual can be found [here](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/J3455-ITX.pdf), and the relevant section as an image below:

[image: Image of J3455-ITX Manual, Page 16]

My question is: Do these clames have any basis in reality or is it all marketing-speak designed to sell people stuff they don't need?

Answer (score 2):

Often the features of a TPM are not easy to leverage for non-programmers.  You could leverage a TPM in order to connect via SSH to a Web server; see a walkthrough guide at https://security.stackexchange.com/a/179422/68088

But average users can see an immediate benefit in encrypting their hard drive, for example with BitLocker. The private key which enables decryption of such an encrypted drive would be stored inside the TPM. The TPM has certain properties such as anti-hammering, isolation of keys and non-exportability which make it highly resistant to remote manipulation.